# How to print only specific text to multiline window in pysimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a situation where I am creating application which is storing log information. I have added UI using pysimplegui package. what I want to achieve is

1. Print some information into text file
2. Print few information line to UI multiline box.

Currently whatever I have printed is going to multiline window.
Attaching code below which is small replica of my bigger code.

```
import threading
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import schedule
THREAD_EVENT = '-THREAD-'
cp = sg.cprint
def the_thread(window):
    def the_thread1():
        print("Avoid this line to get printed into the UI")
        #fruits = [1, "banana", "cherry"]
        for x in range(10):
            print("Avoid this line to get printed into the UI")
            if x == 5:
                #print("x:" + str(x))
                print("Avoid this line to get printed into the UI")
                window.write_event_value('-THREAD-', (threading.current_thread().name, "NMDC","THIS IS MESSAGE")) 
                #cp('This is cheating from the thread', c='white on red')
                print("Avoid this line to get printed into the UI")
    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(the_thread1)
    while 1:
        
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    """
    The demo will display in the multiline info about the event and values dictionary as it is being
    returned from window.read()
    Every time "Start" is clicked a new thread is started
    Try clicking "Dummy" to see that the window is active while the thread stuff is happening in the background
    """

    layout = [  [sg.Text('Output Area - cprint\'s route to here', font='Any 15')],
                [sg.Multiline(size=(65,20), key='-ML-', autoscroll=True, reroute_stdout=True, write_only=True, reroute_cprint=True)],
                [sg.T('Input so you can see data in your dictionary')],
                [sg.Input(key='-IN-', size=(30,1))],
                [sg.B('Start A Thread'), sg.B('Dummy'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ,
    [sg.Text("TotaL messages ",font=('HP Simplified',9),size=(20, 1)),sg.Input("0000",size=(20, 2),key='-msgcount-')]]

    window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

    while True:             # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()
        #cp(event, values)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event.startswith('Start'):
             
            
             threading.Thread(target=the_thread, args=(window,), daemon=True).start()
                      
        if event == THREAD_EVENT:
            #cp(f'Data from the thread ', colors='white on purple', end='')
            #cp(f'{values[THREAD_EVENT]}', colors='white on blue')
            print("Avoid this line to get printed into the UI")
            ## Print only below line of code to multiline window. ignore the other print command
            cp(values[THREAD_EVENT][1]+ ":" + values[THREAD_EVENT][2])
            window.Element('-msgcount-').update(values[THREAD_EVENT][1]+ ":" + values[THREAD_EVENT][2])
            print("Avoid this line to get printed into the UI")
            
            
            #window.Element('-msgcount-').update(values[THREAD_EVENT][1])
            
    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please help me. I tried searching doc but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Initiate `sg.Multiline` with option `reroute_stdout=False`, call `window['-ML-'].update(text, append=True)`.

Comment: @JasonYang- Tried this but still doesn't solve the issue